# Sympy -power variable equation fail (bond yield)

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to sympy and am trying to get it to solve an equation for me. I've been having problems with the full equation so have simplified it down and I believe the challenge is having a -ve variable. For example

```
y=symbols('y')
eqn=Eq(4*2.71828**(y*5),200)
solve(eqn,y)
```

The above works fine, and gives an answer of 0.782405127372565

However, what I really want to do is have a **-y**, like the below. This gives me no answer. Any ideas?

```
y=symbols('y') 
eqn=Eq(4*2.71828**(-y*5),200)
solve(eqn,y)
```

Comment: I think this is just a bug that should be reported to sympy on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2.71828**(y*5)` looks bad to give to a symbolic library that searches for exact solutions. Please use `exp(-y*5)`.  In general, it is a good idea to [avoid floats](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers) whenever possible.

To avoid complex numbers as solutions, you can restrict `y` to `real`.
Whenever possible, sympy returns exact symbolic solutions. You can convert them to numbers via `N()` or `.evalf()`.

```py
from sympy import Eq, symbols, solve, exp, N

y = symbols('y', real=True)
eqn = Eq(4 * exp(-y * 5), 200)
sol = solve(eqn, y)
print(sol, [N(s) for s in sol])
```

Output:

```
[log(2000**(1/5)/10)] [-0.782404601085629]
```

Without `real=True`, you get all 5 complex solutions.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. That's really useful to know .... I now have it working and given myself a few things to learn in the process.